# Is the average default rate of a bond class annual or life of the bond?

Tags: bonds

In [some web sites](https://seekingalpha.com/article/282080-4-aaa-rated-companies-with-attractive-yields) I see listed various "default rates" for different types of bonds, AAA, AA+, etc.

Are those default rates per year, or over the life of the bond?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure if you are asking about

1. Probability of default
2. Default ratios of rating classes

I will just try to elaborate on above:

1. Ratings are tied to the likelihood of the company going default, or the *Probability of default* (PD). PD is exponential with AAA having a PD in the ballpark of 0.01% (or similar) and C being maybe 80%. PD is usually expressed as the probability of default within 12 months. So a PD of 1% would mean that there is a 1% chance that the company will default within 1 year.
2. Default ratios will relate to how many companies in each rating class that will actually default. This will be in percentage, not related to periods.